# excel export to tab delimited text file with | to start each row

Tags: excel, text, export-to-text

I am working on a project that requires non technical people to edit an excel file.

The file contains 2 columns, one is a key and one is a value. The key is an integer and the value is html.  I need a text file to be generated by a non technical person that takes the form:

```
|[key][ tab \t][value]
|[key][ tab \t][value]
|[key][ tab \t][value]
```

The | is needed because the html could be multiline.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Is the data already formatted with keys in column A and values in column B?

Comment: No specific version in mind but most likely 2010. Column a is keys and column b is values.  I was hoping to hide the | from the user editing the excel. So putting | at the beginning of all keys is not ideal.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to insert a column before a, place | in the column, and then hide it? Exporting the Excel file as .txt will put the desired tabs between fields. (Although it will place an extra tab between the | and the key.)

Comment: I thought about this but users will be adding/subtracting rows as needed. I'm loading the values into javascript and I dont want there to be a ton of empty lines with just | in them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll need a dab of VBA to get it working. This should get you started.

```
Sub writeKeysValues()
Dim i As Integer
Dim outFile As String
Dim fNum1 As Integer

'Open file
outFile = "C:\temp\outfile.txt"
fNum1 = FreeFile()
Open outFile For Output As fNum1

'loop through non-blanks
i = 1
With Worksheets("Book1")
    Do Until .Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
        Print #fNum1, "|" & .Cells(i, 1).Value & vbTab & .Cells(i, 2).Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End With

'All done
Close #fNum1
End Sub
```

Notes:

- You will have to save the file as an Excel-macro-enabled spreadsheet (.xlsm).
- It will stop reading at a blank key.
- Writing is hardcoded to the C:\temp\outfile.txt.

This will win no code design contests, but it should give you an idea of how to write it out with the pipes and tabs exactly as you desire.

Comment: passed the issue onto my client to sort out. But the idea was to be able to do a simple save as. i.e. not have them running any scripts ect.

Comment: You have a choice between putting out the way Excel wants, with a save-as, or putting it out the way the client wants, using VBA or another programming language. I don't think there's a neutral ground, especially with your constraint for not having a hidden pipe in a hidden column. (But I'm willing to be corrected!)